# Every second data row has a null relationship in EF Core

Tags: sqlite, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a database where I have mocked data in a few rows in a table called `Bets`, by filling the first four rows with the number `1` and the next four rows with the number `2`. There is a `Team` table with team rows corresponding to IDs `1` and `2`.

I'm using .NET Core 2.1.0 and EF Core 2.1.0 with a SQLite database. There is a class `Bet` with a many-to-one relationship to a class `Team`. They look as follows:

```
public class Bet
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int TeamId { get; set; }
    public Team Team { get; set; }
}

public class Team
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

To access the data, I'm using this syntax:

```
public class BettingDbContext : DbContext
{
    public BettingDbContext(DbContextOptions<BettingDbContext> options)
        : base(options) { }

    public virtual DbSet<Bet> Bets { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Team> Teams { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Bet>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("Bets");
            entity.HasIndex(e => e.Id)
                .IsUnique();
            entity.HasOne(b => b.Team)
                  .WithOne();
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Team>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("Teams");
            entity.HasIndex(e => e.Id)
                .IsUnique();
        });
    }
}
```

When I get back results, ***every second*** row has `null` set to its relational property `Team`. Here is some output from the Immediate Window:

```
> bets[0].Team
(null)
> bets[1].Team
{betting.DAL.Primitives.Team}
    Id: 1
    Name: "Uruguay"
> bets[2].Team
(null)
> bets[3].Team
{betting.DAL.Primitives.Team}
    Id: 1
    Name: "Uruguay"
> bets[4].Team
(null)
> bets[5].Team
{betting.DAL.Primitives.Team}
    Id: 2
    Name: "Russia"
> bets[6].Team
(null)
> bets[7].Team
{betting.DAL.Primitives.Team}
    Id: 2
    Name: "Russia"
>
```

Any ideas what could cause this?

Comment: From your explanation of the data, the `Bet` -> `Team` relationship seems to be many-to-one, hence `.WithOne()` should be `.WithMany()`.

Comment: `me.blind = true`. Thanks. Post an answer and I'll accept

Comment: You are welcome, and lol, what a comment :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to

> filling the first four rows with the number 1 and the next four rows with the number 2

the relationship between `Bet` and `Team` has to be many-to-many. While with the fluent API you are telling EF Core to treat it as one-to-one, hence it gets confused when start processing the data - the actual behavior doesn't matter, apparently it is the weird data you are getting, preferably it should be an exception, but anyway, there are a lot things waiting to be implemented in EF Core, so we can live with that.

With that being said, simply change `.WithOne()` to `.WithMany()`. Problem solved.